# How to get access to accessor methods in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

I have a model called `user` and a model called `access_barrier` and a join table between a `user` and `access_barrier` called `barrier_users`.

I have created the following associations for them

```
user.belongsToMany(models.access_barrier, {
  as: "access_barriers_accessible",
  through: "barrier_users",
  foreignKey: "userId",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
  onDelete: "CASCADE"
});

access_barrier.belongsToMany(models.user, {
  as: "users_with_permission",
  through: "barrier_users",
  foreignKey: "barrierId",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
  onDelete: "CASCADE"
});
```

When querying users with the following code I can see all the data come in fine.

```
return models.user
    .findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: models.access_barrier,
            as: "access_barriers_accessible"
          }
        ]
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        resolve(result);
    })
    .catch(models.Sequelize.DatabaseError, function() {
        reject("An error occurred in the database");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        reject(err);
    });
```

The documentation for sequelize mentions that accessor methods are created when using the above functionality as mentioned below

> `Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserProject'});`
>
> `User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: 'UserProject'});`
>
> This will create a new model called UserProject with the equivalent foreign keys projectId and userId. Whether the attributes are camelcase or not depends on the two models joined by the table (in this case User and Project).
>
> Defining through is required. Sequelize would previously attempt to autogenerate names but that would not always lead to the most logical setups.
>
> This will add methods getUsers, setUsers, addUser,addUsers to Project, and getProjects, setProjects, addProject, and addProjects to User.

How do I know the method names that are added for my models, where exactly can I view them? How do I get access to them?

I used `Object.keys(models.user)` and got the data below

```
[ 'sequelize',
  'options',
  'associations',
  'underscored',
  'tableName',
  '_schema',
  '_schemaDelimiter',
  'rawAttributes',
  'primaryKeys',
  '_timestampAttributes',
  '_readOnlyAttributes',
  '_hasReadOnlyAttributes',
  '_isReadOnlyAttribute',
  '_dataTypeChanges',
  '_dataTypeSanitizers',
  '_booleanAttributes',
  '_dateAttributes',
  '_hstoreAttributes',
  '_rangeAttributes',
  '_jsonAttributes',
  '_geometryAttributes',
  '_virtualAttributes',
  '_defaultValues',
  'fieldRawAttributesMap',
  'fieldAttributeMap',
  'uniqueKeys',
  '_hasBooleanAttributes',
  '_isBooleanAttribute',
  '_hasDateAttributes',
  '_isDateAttribute',
  '_hasHstoreAttributes',
  '_isHstoreAttribute',
  '_hasRangeAttributes',
  '_isRangeAttribute',
  '_hasJsonAttributes',
  '_isJsonAttribute',
  '_hasVirtualAttributes',
  '_isVirtualAttribute',
  '_hasGeometryAttributes',
  '_isGeometryAttribute',
  '_hasDefaultValues',
  'attributes',
  'tableAttributes',
  'primaryKeyAttributes',
  'primaryKeyAttribute',
  'primaryKeyField',
  '_hasPrimaryKeys',
  '_isPrimaryKey',
  'autoIncrementAttribute',
  '_scope',
  '_scopeNames',
  'associate' ]
```

On checking out what `associations` has it was

```
{ access_barriers_incharge: access_barriers_incharge,
  access_barriers_admin: access_barriers_admin,
  admin: admin,
  access_barriers_accessible: access_barriers_accessible,
  barriers_accessed: barriers_accessed }
```

Comment: Try using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a list of property names.

Comment: @FranciscoMateo I updated the question with the result, I don't think there's much there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this article that allowed me to figure out what magic methods are associated with a sequelize object.

In short you can use the following code on a sequelize object to get its magic methods.

```
console.log(Object.keys(sequelizeObject.__proto__));
```

[Feeling The Magic with Sequelize Magic Methods](https://medium.com/@jasmine.esplago.munoz/feeling-the-magic-with-sequelize-magic-methods-e9cc89ecdcc5)